# Viewing queries coming from outside Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am aware of the query_history views associated with account_usage and with the information_schema query_history function family. However, I cannot find a way to monitor what queries are being sent to Snowflake from outside Snowflake. For example, I have Power BI hitting a Snowflake database but queries PBI is sending to Snowflake don't seem to appear in query history. Is this possible to see?

Comment: Maybe naive question, but aren't you using a dedicated user/warehouse to connect from PBI to SF?

Comment: Yes but what difference does that make?

Comment: [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) - columns WAREHOUSE_ID/USER_NAME/ROLE_NAME could be used to determine that specific queries originated from Power BI

Comment: I agree that should work but PBI queries are not showing up in the result set returned by the view.

Comment: Account_usage schema has 2-3hours delay depending on view

Comment: Yes, true, but PBI has been sending queries to Snowflake for the past couple days.

Comment: I would try: `select *
from table(information_schema.query_history_by_user(USER_NAME =>'<power_bi_user_here>'))
order by start_time desc;`

Comment: I found my PBI queries. The problem was that the database name in the result set was being set to NULL and I was looking for the specific database I knew was being hit. If you want to type up your comments as an answer, I'll vote it up and accept it for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries run against Snowflake could be found in [Query History view](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html)(ACCOUNT_USAGE schema has 45min data latency).

If the external tool(here Power BI) is using dedicated virtual warehouse/user/role then it is easy to filter the records by one of the columns: `WAREHOUSE_ID/USER_NAME/ROLE_NAME`.

Another option is to use dedicated table-valued function:

```
select * 
from table(information_schema.query_history_by_user(USER_NAME =>'<power_bi_user>')) 
order by start_time desc;
```

Comment: One thing to note for anyone reading this. The name of the database that PBI is issuing the query against will not appear in the DATABASE_NAME column of the result set. It will be NULL.